# Why do I need a service to read the google Firebase token?

Tags: android, firebase

I use this code in MainActivity which is not extending FirebaseInstanceIdService to read the token generated by google firebase:

```
String token= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

However according to Firebase documentation I have to create a service which extends FirebaseInstanceIdService and retrieves the token on token refresh:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    }
    }
}
```

Why do I need to run  a service to read the token and What are the limitations of reading token from a simple activity?

Answer (score 1):

There's two things to keep in mind.

1) The token could change at any time, at which point the old token becomes invalid.  You don't want to be using an invalid token, or your app features that depend on it might not work.

2) The token could be refreshed when you don't have an activity started.  In order to respond to a token refresh that could happen at any time, you'll need a Service to handle that event in the background as soon as it occurs.